# pow function and long int causing problems

Tags: c, gcc, encryption, int, pow

I am trying to impliment RSA encryption scheme. It goes something like this:

`encrypted data = ((message)^e) % n` and `decrypted data = ((encrypted data)^d) % n`

I tried to implement this in c. Here is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){

    long int num = 3255859; 
    long int encrypt =(int)pow((double) num,3) % 33;
    printf("%ld\n",encrypt);

    return 0;

}
```

I compiled this using `gcc -Werror -g -o encrypt encrypt.c -lm`

This is the output I get = `-2`, which is obviously wrong. When i try this code for smaller numbers, I get the right result. For eg:

when I set `num = 2`, I get the right result which is `8`

I know I am either type casting wrong or I am running out of boundaries somewhere. I do need to use this code to encrypt large numbers like the one in the code above.

Could you please point out where I am going wrong.

Thanks

EDIT:

Ok as per suggestion from @Micael Oliver here is the modified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){

    unsigned long long  num = 3255859; 

    long long encrypt =(long long)pow((double) num,3) % 33;

    printf("%llu\n",encrypt);

    long long decrypt =(long long)pow((double) encrypt,7) % 33;

    printf("%llu\n",decrypt);

    return 0;

}
```

here is the output of this code :

```
Notra:Desktop Sukhvir$ gcc -Werror -g -o encrypt encrypt.c -lm
Notra:Desktop Sukhvir$ ./encrypt
18446744073709551608
18446744073709551614
```

which is obviously wrong as the 2nd outpt should have been 3255859

Comment: Try using `long long`, but only if you expect your numbers to remain under 2^63, positive or negative.

Comment: I tried with long long int on both num and encrypt ... still the same result  = -2 :(

Comment: It's somewhat substandard to use `long long int`.  Usually people use just `long long`.  Also, if you only want positive numbers, use `unsigned long long`.
For `long long`, you can use `%lld`, and for the unsigned version use `%llu`.

Comment: You should use `long long encrypt =(long long)pow((double) num,3) % 33;`

Comment: There is still a problem with your solution though.  `pow` returns a `double`, which generally has only 15 digits of precision (reliably), even when a number might be larger than that.  Then when you convert it to a `long long`, you won't regain those digits you lost, so your mod might end up being wrong.

Comment: that is exactly whats happening (see my edit to original post ) ... how may I go about fixing this. Is there another way to raise to the power in c perhaps ??

Comment: First of all, you should get 34515102827311469 % 33 = 11.  I'm noticing you have a mix of signed and unsigned numbers.  `%llu` should only be used for unsigned.  In terms of fixing the other problem though, there isn't anything built into C.  Here's an article on Wikipedia that shows a fast way of implementing `pow`: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring

Otherwise you can do some research into libraries that support large numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a bit of a mix of unsigned and signed numbers in your code - you should try to avoid this when possible.  Also you're attempting to use `%llu` on a signed long long - you should use `%lld` in this case.

But there is a more subtle problem in play here.  In this line:

```
long long encrypt =(long long)pow((double) num,3) % 33;
```

`pow` returns a `double`, which won't guarantee all the precision you're looking for.  You're going to end up losing a few digits when you cast to `long long`.  Unfortunately C doesn't provide a good alternative for computing exponentials, so you'll need to implement something yourself or use a library (some of the other answers have suggested some).

If you want to implement one yourself, a great article on fast exponentiation by squaring can be found on Wikipedia here: [Exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)

They provide some pseudo-code that should be obvious for coding in C.

But lastly, in general your code is going to be limited by the size of `long long`, or whatever type you choose.  Ultimately for large numbers you should use some other library, or find a better algorithm.  In this case, you're computing a power and then taking a modulus - which is exactly what Modular Exponentation algorithms can accomplish without having to deal with these libraries.  You can find a Wikipedia article here: [Modular Exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation)

Answer (score 0):

one suggestion was to use another datatype like long long:

```
3255859^3 ==  34514116960466804779
ULLONG_MAX == 18446744073709551615  // this is the minimum guaranteed
```

So, unsigned long long may not work.  In general changing datatypes has limits. 
Another more robust approach you can consider is to use GMP - free.
[gmp manual](http://gmplib.org/manual/)  --

--  you can download gmp at this site as well.

code snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <gmp.h>

int main()
{
    mpz_t rop, base, exp, mod;
    mpz_init2(rop,128); 
    mpz_init2(base,128); 
    mpz_init2(exp,128); 
    mpz_init2(mod,128);
    mpz_set_ui(base, 3255859);
    mpz_set_ui(exp, 3);
    mpz_set_ui(mod, 33);
    mpz_powm_sec (rop, base, exp, mod);
    gmp_printf ("result %Zd\n", rop);    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that you don't need to be able to represent num³, just num², in the type used. This is because you can perform modular reduction after each operation (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

As long as your numbers are at most half the size of the type you're working in, you can do something like this:

```
(((num * num) % 33) * num) % 33
```

In general, for anything practical for cryptographic purposes, you'll need much larger values and a computational framework to work with 1024+ bit numbers. For this you can use existing code (I would recommend `libtommath` from `libtomcrypt`, definitely *not* GMP) or write your own.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not GMP?

Comment: Because it's unsafe - it `abort()`s your program if any allocation attempt fails. It's also gratuitously complex and non-portable.

Comment: LibTomMath appears to be unsupported - [github site](https://github.com/libtom/libtommath)   [LibTom.org](http://libtom.org/?page=index&newsitems=5&whatfile=ltm)

Comment: A sign of good software is that it's still perfectly usable after a long time of no updates. :-) Seriously, libtommath is used in the Dropbear SSH implementation and various other security products. I have not performed a detailed audit of it, but based on the limited reading I have done, it's high-quality code that makes it quickly clear to the reader whether it's correct, rather than obfuscating everything with gratuitous complexity.